Unable to Export POWER BI Visual level data using access token authentication
I am trying to connect power bi reports which are hosted on power bi service. I have two versions of code in my JupyterLab.One is connecting using service principal and second one is DeviceCodeLoginAuthentication.In service principal method i am unable to load report when I print the report it says Report().
**service principal method :**
from powerbiclient import Report, models
import requests

tenant_id = 'AAA'
client_id = 'BBB'
client_secret = 'CCC'  # Be cautious with secrets!

url = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token'

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}

body = {
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
    'client_id': client_id,
    'client_secret': client_secret,
    'scope': 'https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default'
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=body)
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Parse the access token from the response
    access_token = response.json().get('access_token')
    #print("Access Token acquired successfully!")
    #print(access_token)  # For debugging purposes only, don't print secrets in production
else:
    # Print the error details if the token request failed
    print(f"Error: {response.status_code}")
    print(f"Error response: {response.json()}")


group_id="DDD"
report_id="EEE"

report = Report(group_id=group_id, report_id=report_id, auth=access_token)
report

**DeviceCodeLoginAuthentication method(HERE REPORT IS LOADING SUCESSFULLY) :**
from powerbiclient import Report, models
group_id="DDD"
report_id="EEE"
from powerbiclient.authentication import DeviceCodeLoginAuthentication
device_path= DeviceCodeLoginAuthentication()
display1 = Report(group_id=group_id, report_id=report_id, auth=device_path)
display1


please suggest what is missing in method one which is service principal.

You’re using a Service Principal for authentication, but the powerbi-jupyter library doesn’t support that. This library needs an Embed token, not an AAD token.
In the "powerbi-jupyter" library, we use the "embed for your organization" scenario, which specifically requires an Azure Active Directory (AAD) token. So, the Service Principal method won’t work with this library.
For more details you can refer this documentation:
Permission tokens needed to embed a Power BI app - Power BI | Microsoft Learn
